# Add Image Column to Telerik Radgrid

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, radgridview

Using c#.net4.5 telerik, Visual Studio 2012. Winforms.

Simple question, how do I add a new column in a code that can store images in a `radgridview`?

My old winforms code with `datagridview` used to be this.

```
DataGridViewImageCell p2 = new DataGridViewImageCell();
dgv_Pareto.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewImageColumn() { CellTemplate = p2, FillWeight = 1, HeaderText = "p2", Name = "p2", Width = 30 });
```

Why is this not the case in `telerik`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `GridViewImageColumn`. More info [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-columns-gridviewimagecolumn.html).

Comment: ah i wasnt looking for the obvious! well got it working thanks for the help, unfortunatly its not liking my image, i cann just add the image to the grid.cell[index].value iterating through the rows? or is this not the method to do it?

Comment: You should be able to use a Bitmap or an Image type. What is the type you are using?

You can set an image cell value as follows:
radGridView1.Rows[index].Cells["ColumnName"].Value = yourImage;

Comment: nah i sorted it, was correct only i forgot to populate the image i only created. lol. cheers for that